# Replace Specified String And All Subsequent Characters

Tags: regex, bash, sed, text-parsing

I want to use Sed to replace all characters **after and including** a specified string as shown below:

**Keyword**

```
#specific-keyword
```

**Input**

```
Some text amongst which lies a #specific-keyword and everything else that follows.
```

**Output**

```
Some text amongst which lies a
```

I came up with something like this:

```
"Some text amongst which lies a #specific-keyword and everything else that follows." | sed "s/#specific-keyword*/ /g"
```

But it only removes the specific keyword but not the words after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out the answer, my regular expression was wrong. I needed to add the `.*` to the end of the specific keyword like this:

```
sed 'Some text amongst which lies a #specific-keyword and everything else that follows./#specific-keyword.*/ /g'
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will not give you what you want.

Comment: @sjsam how so? Am I missing a particular case?

Comment: The simplest I could think of is `sed 's/#specific-keyword.*$//'`. But this assumes that there is only one occurrence of `#specific-keyword` in the input.. In fact you need to append to the question what you would like to do if you've multiple occurrences of `#specific-keyword`

Comment: @sjsam, his "_replace all characters after and including a specified string_" implies removal of everything including possible occurrences of the keyword. Another thing is that he replaces with a space, but not removes (in this answer).

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov indeed you are correct, can you recommend me a place to get started with my regex? Like a *zero to hero* kind of a guide?

Comment: @atefth, [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) is an excellent resource for any level of knowledge